# Specman: debugging un-accessible memory

Tags: specman

We have a huge environment, built from sub environments which are maintained by many users.
When we run a test, we see that we have a GC every 10us, when we use "show mem" we see that we have about 3GB as un-accessible memory, after the GC it's removed.

How can we determine what causes this huge consumption in our memory?
Using iprof mem, didn't give any "big" memory consumer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Specman auto GC? you can check that by doing "config mem" at specman prompt and check that the -automatic_gc_settings=STANDARD. if not, try using the auto gc and see if it makes any change. if yes, you may need to increase the process size. are you running in 32 or 64bit mode? 
to better understand the problem and assist you, it will be best if you run with SPECMAN_MEMORY_FULL_DEBUG env variable and send Cadence support the resulting log.
If you open a case for cadence support and send me the number, I can assist you further.

Regards,
Semadar
Customer Support Manager @Cadence